# Is .winmd file platform independent?

Tags: windows-runtime, nuget, win-universal-app

I have developed a C/C++ based *Windows Runtime Component* for *Universal Windows*, and I am now trying to include it in a NuGet plackage.

With NuGet version 3, the *runtimes* folder has been introduced, see [here](http://docs.nuget.org/Create/uwp-create) for details. Unfortunately, this documentation does not give much information on how to deal with *Windows Runtime Component*s.

I have organized the files in the NuGet package like this:

```
└───MyNuGetPackage  
     ├───lib  
     │   └───uap  
     │         MyRuntimeLibrary.winmd  
     │  
     ├───build  
     │   └───uap  
     │         MyNuGetPackage.targets  
     │  
     └───runtimes  
         ├───win10-x86  
         │   └───native  
         │         MyRuntimeLibrary.dll  
         │  
         ├───win10-x64  
         │   └───native  
         │         MyRuntimeLibrary.dll  
         │  
         └───win10-arm  
             └───native  
                   MyRuntimeLibrary.dll
```

The *MyNuGetPackage.targets* file is used in the build procedure to add a reference to the *.winmd* file and explicitly specify the implementation *.dll*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Target Name="InjectReference" BeforeTargets="ResolveAssemblyReferences">
    <ItemGroup Condition=" '$(Platform)' == 'x86' or '$(Platform)' == 'x64' or '$(Platform)' == 'ARM'">
      <Reference Include="Dicom.Imaging.Codec">
        <HintPath>$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\..\lib\uap\MyRuntimeLibrary.winmd</HintPath>
        <Implementation>MyRuntimeLibrary.dll</Implementation>
      </Reference>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>  
</Project>
```

As far as I have been able to tell, this NuGet package composition works; the relevant implementation file is selected when building for the different platforms *x86*, *x64* and *ARM*.

However, with the above approach, I am only including the *.winmd* file from one target platform (*x86* in this specific case). **Is this really OK?** It seems to work, but is really the *.winmd* file platform independent?

---

In case the *.winmd* file is platform *dependent*, I have tried to add platform target specific *.winmd* files under the *runtimes* folder, like this:

```
     └───runtimes  
         ├───win10-x86  
         │   └───lib  
         │       └───uap  
         │             MyRuntimeLibrary.winmd  
         │   └───native  
         │         MyRuntimeLibrary.dll
```

and I have updated the *MyNuGetPackage.targets* file accordingly. However, when I install this alternative NuGet package and try to build for a specific platform, I get a payload build error that the *MyRuntimeLibrary.winmd* file is being copied to the output directory from two separate locations, both the *lib\uap* folder and the *runtimes* sub-folder.

It also does not help to exclude the top *lib\uap* folder altogether; if I do, the build procedure does not find any *.winmd* file reference at all.

If the *.winmd* file is platform dependent after all, how should I organize the *.winmd* and *.dll* files in my NuGet package to ensure that the package installs sufficiently on all platforms?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It probably helps to understand what a .winmd file really is.  It is a reformulation of the COM type libraries of old, you might have run into a .tlb file before.  Might have looked at its content before with the OleView.exe SDK utility, File + View Typelib command.

Much the same as .NET metadata, your profile says you definitely used them before.  Files you find back in the References node of a C# project.  You might have looked at them before with ildasm.exe or a .NET decompiler like Reflector or ILSpy.  Or the IDE's Go To Declaration command.  You already know that such references are platform independent.

Microsoft retired the .tlb file format and replaced it with the .NET metadata file format.  A format that was flexible enough to also express COM declarations.  And expandable enough to express WinRT declarations, the kind that could not be hammered into the .tlb format.  Like generics and attributes, heavily used by the *language projection* to make COM client code easier to write.  Pretty good move, Microsoft had to do very little work to change existing tooling, like the C# compiler, to work with .winmd files.

Long story short, it behaves just like .NET assemblies and COM type libraries at compile-time.  The compiler uses it to retrieve type declarations.  You *can* make it platform dependent by accident, like using `int` when you meant to use `IntPtr`.  But the language projection you'd use in whatever language you program in makes this a very rare accident.  And quickly discovered when you test.

Comment: It's not true that `winmd` files never contain code. You can try this out by building a new runtime component in VS 2015 for example. The binary produced will be a single file that contains both the meta data and the implementation of the class.

Comment: Just chiming in...A C++ runtime component's .winmd file only ever contains metadata. C# runtime components however does contain both meta data and implementation.